# Pandas Calculate percentage by column values

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe is like below

| id | age |
| --- | --- |
| a | 30-40 |
| b | 30-40 |
| c | 30-40 |
| d | 40-50 |
| e | 40-50 |

The count of '30-40' is 3, the count of '40-50' is 2.
The output I want is just value, I don't care about the format.
Here is the output

| age | percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 30-40 | 60.00% |
| 40-50 | 40.00% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True`, then multiple by `100` and change format to `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = (df['age'].value_counts(normalize=True)
                .mul(100)
                .rename_axis('age')
                .reset_index(name='percentage'))
print (df1)
     age  percentage
0  30-40        60.0
1  40-50        40.0
```